# What are those last numbers after the browser info in the apache access logs?

Tags: apache, logging

In the apache access logs I have two entries for a GET, the only difference between them  are those last numbers after the browser info? What are those last numbers after the browser info in the apache access logs?

```
apache -access.log-20160128:Jan 28 05:57:29  apache_access: : 116.14.224.103 - - 2016-01-28T05:57:29+0100 "GET /?context=0a78181e0vvtJ1p8pKIBnoByApdDb7Z9&host=regular&locale=en_US&topicId=295 HTTP/1.1" 200 7542 "https://www.1and1.com/customized?__lf=Order-Tariff" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" 1677
apache -access.log-20160128:Jan 28 05:57:29  apache_access: : 116.14.224.103 - - 2016-01-28T05:57:29+0100 "GET /?context=0a78181e0vvtJ1p8pKIBnoByApdDb7Z9&host=regular&locale=en_US&topicId=295 HTTP/1.1" 200 7542 "https://www.1and1.com/customized?__lf=Order-Tariff" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" 1300
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a format to the logs [here](https://docs.webarch.net/wiki/Apache_Log_Files):

The access log format is based on the NCSA extended/combined log format and these are the Apache directives used to define the logging for each VirtualHost:

```
LogLevel error
ErrorLog  /home/example/logs/error.log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
CustomLog /home/example/logs/access.log combinedio
```

So according to the above description those numbers should be `%I` or the bytes received.